# Estimates for truncated prime zeta function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

We know that the prime zeta function $P(s) = \sum \limits_{p} p^{-s}$ is absolutely convergent for $\Re(s) > 1$ but I could not find an estimate for these values. More specifically, I am interested in the sum $\sum \limits_{x \le p \le y} p^{-s}$ when $s$ is a positive integer $\ge 2$. If such estimates are not available, even the numerical values of $P(s)$ for the above values of $s$ would suffice.

Comment: Under the RH $$\sum_{ p \in [x,y]}p^{-s}= \sum_{n \in [x,y]}\frac{n^{-s}}{\log n} + O( \int_x^y t^{-\Re(s)-1/2}\log (t) dt)$$ what do you expect more ?

Comment: Thanks! Are there unconditional results? Also, can you maybe give a reference for the above estimate?

Comment: From partial summation any error term for $\pi(x)-\sum_{n \le x }1/\log n= \pi(x)-Li(x)+O(1)$ translates to an error term for $\sum_{ p \in [x,y]}p^{-s}- \sum_{n \in [x,y]}\frac{n^{-s}}{\log n}$. The PNT is unconditional.

Comment: Oh okay, that should help.